# Cannot create instance of MainViewModel with Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, dagger, dagger-hilt

I'm testing hilt with a simple project, what I want to achieve is to generate an instance of my MainViewModel with Hilt this is what I have done so far

### MainActivity

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
 ...
}
```

### MainFragment

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainFragment : Fragment(),MainAdapter.OnTragoClickListener {

    private val viewModel by activityViewModels<MainViewModel>()

...
}
```

### MainViewModel

```
class MainViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(private val repo:Repo):ViewModel(){
...
}
```

### RepoImpl

```
class RepoImpl @Inject constructor(private val dataSource: DataSource): Repo {
...
}
```

### DataSourceImpl

```
class DataSourceImpl @Inject constructor(private val tragosDao: TragosDao): DataSource{
...
}
```

Now , this is the architecture the app follows, here `Repo` and `DataSource` are simple interfaces that I use.

So after this I generate all that hilt requires to generate the instances

### BaseApplication

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class BaseApplication: Application() {
}
```

### AppModule

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRoomInstance(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context
    ) = Room.databaseBuilder(
            context,
            AppDatabase::class.java,
            "tabla_tragos")
            .build()

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideTragosDao(db: AppDatabase) = db.tragoDao()

}
```

The module above provides tragoDao() so I can access it in my `DataSourceImpl`, since I need an unique instance of this database I use `@Singleton` on its provide

Then I just create another module that will let hilt know about the implementations of the interfaces above

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityRetainedComponent::class)
abstract class ActivityModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindDataSource(dataSource:DataSourceImpl): DataSource

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindRepo(repo: RepoImpl): Repo

}
```

Since I need an instance of the MainViewModel , I scope this module with `ActivityRetainedComponent`

After compiling the app I get this error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class
> com.g.tragosapp.ui.viewmodel.MainViewModel

### Dependencies

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'

dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
  implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
  implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

  //Navigation Components
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0"
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0"
  implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

  //ViewModel y LiveData
  implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'

  // KTX - Viewmodel Y Livedata
  implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
  implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.0-alpha05"

  implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5"
  implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.1.0"

  //utils
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

  //Corutinas
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.3"

  //Retrofit
  implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0'
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
  implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
  implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.0'

  implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'

  //Room
  implementation 'androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.5'
  implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5"
  kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5"

  //Hilt
  implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28-alpha"
  kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha"
  implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha02'


  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

I have also added

```
  implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5"
  implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.1.0"
  implementation "androidx.core:core:1.3.1"
```

which has not made any difference

Comment: add `kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha02'`

Comment: Wow, this worked, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class RepoImpl
```

Should be

```
@Singleton class RepoImpl
```

And same for `DataSourceImpl`

Then change `@InstallIn(ActivityRetainedComponent::class)` to `@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)` (used to be ApplicationComponent)

And also make sure to have all these deps (at the time of writing):

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        dagger_version = '2.41'
    }

dependencies {
    classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$dagger_version"
}
```

and

```
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$dagger_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$dagger_version"
kaptTest "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$dagger_version"
kaptAndroidTest "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$dagger_version"
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'
```

Comment: I seems that I dont have SingletonComponent::class to install in, also, whats the difference of doing those classes singleton ? thanks

Comment: Marking the singletons and also adding the ApplicationComponent returns the same error creating the instance

Comment: If you make them singleton, then they will share the same scope as the component I'm trying to install it in. That should reduce possibility of some errors. ApplicationComponent is being renamed to SingletonComponent, it might differ depending in your current version. If the HiltViewModelProviderFactory is still not being used, check if you have the `apply plugin` to actually run the Hilt gradle plugin.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Can you please help me on one doubt is that. Hilt does not work with presenter or view class ?

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha I can't possibly know your setup so I cannot answer your question, nor what you are looking for. "Presenters" aren't the norm in Android development.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Can you please check this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/67761348/3946958 . I have posted the question there.Than