# Hilt :- Not able to use the @AndroidEntryPoint in the AppCompatActivity getting DefaultV iewModelFactories exceptions?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, dagger-hilt

I want to use the Hilt in my project for getting the helper class object as the common for my activity. I have tried the below lines of code for it

**Manifest file** entry

```
 <application
        android:name=".application.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="false"
```

My **AppController** class

```
@HiltAndroidApp
public class AppController extends Application implements Configuration.Provider {
}
```

Please check my **gradles** file for it

```
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.3"

implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.4'
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.36'
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.31.2-alpha'
```

Please check my **classPath** entry below

```
classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.36"
```

Now please check my **NVModule Module** class in which i have used the Hilt

```
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class NVModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideDeviceDiagnosticHelper(): DeviceDiagnosticHelper{
        return DeviceDiagnosticHelper()
    }
}
```

Now please check the **Activity** class in which i have injected the Hilt object

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
public class AutomaticTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


  private AutomaticTestPresenter automaticTestPresenter;

  private AutomaticTestView automaticTestView;

  
  ActivityDeviceDiagnosticBinding mBinding;

  @Inject
  DeviceDiagnosticHelper deviceDiagnosticHelper;
}
```

But I am getting the following exception while Running the app please check it once

**Exception**:-

> /home/..../com/my/app/activity/Hilt_AutomaticTestActivity.java:70: error: method getActivityFactory in class DefaultViewModelFactories cannot be applied to given types;
> return DefaultViewModelFactories.getActivityFactory(this);
> ^
> required: ComponentActivity,Factory
> found: Hilt_AutomaticTestActivity
> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Please help me to short of from this problem

Comment: What is `DeviceDiagnosticHelper`? is it a viewmodel?

Comment: @MayurGajra It is my helper class , which does operations like calculation, getting static list etc

Comment: I checked with your sample code & it works fine with Injecting  `DeviceDiagnosticHelper` .   Is there a `viewmodel` declaration in your code? From exception it seems related to that. If yes, then can you please post code related to that?

Comment: Actually, I am using the MVP architecture, But i getting the exception in class **Activity** that is`AutomaticTestActivity` and it does not even work with Simple class, Please check it once, WHich code you require, please let me know, will post the relevant code there also..Please check the annotation, I am using is right or not..Thanks

Comment: It's strange that you're not using `viewmodel` at all & still getting `DefaultViewModelFactories`  error. If there's no implementation of `viewmodel` in your code then i guess it must be some code generation error by hilt. Try removing `build` & `Invalidate cache & Restart`.

Comment: @MayurGajra . I have tried both removed build and invalid restart. But still it is not working. Please help me with it. Please check my whole code above. I think have done some mistake in it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233091/discussion-between-mayur-gajra-and-ravindra-kushwaha).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be version mismatch. Use following versions:

```
// hilt
implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.36'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.36'
kaptAndroidTest 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.36'
kaptTest 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.36'
// implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation:1.0.0"
// implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-fragment:1.0.0"
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'
```

And

```
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
```

And

```
classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.36'
```

Answer (score 2):

version of dependency for project level and app level must be same.
like :
classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1"

and

implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.38.1"

Answer (score 1):

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.38.1"


implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03'
    kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'
```

worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).